# Why is adding bootstrap to angular not working correctly? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am a beginner in angular. I am trying to add bootstrap in my first project, but it doesn't appear below   in the head section in developer tools. Here is my angularjson code. Thanks in advance.

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-first-project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
```

Comment: Because it's minified and compiled into the scripts.js and styles.js bundles

Comment: removed it from the scripts still not working

Comment: it's working even if you dont see it in the head section explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Steps to use bootstrap in Angular.

1. Install bootstrap

   - `npm install bootstrap --save`
2. In **angular.json** file

   - Under **styles array** import **bootstrap.min.css**

     - `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`
   - Under **scripts array** import **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** file because popper.js is included in bootstrap.bundle.js file. If you import **bootstrap.js** only then you must have to import **popper.js** before **bootstrap.js** For More Information [check Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/contents/)

     - `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"`